# How do I get rid of error #1064

Tags: mysql

Table structure for table `tbl_appointment`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_appointment` (
`ap_id` int( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
`ap_starting` time( 6 ) NOT NULL ,
`ap_ending` time( 6 ) NOT NULL ,
`ap_day` varchar( 255 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL,
>     `ap_ending` time(6) NOT NULL,
>     `ap_day` varchar(255) NOT NULL
>   )' at line 9`

I tried to import the SQL file to phpmyadmin. the file works fine on later version of XAMPP from what I have. I tried to edit the SQL file based on the error but to no avail.

Comment: Could you post that code and error message as text please?

Comment: tried the same code and it worked on my side. tried it on mysql 5.6.26. Please also check mysql error log to see anything there as well?

Comment: isn't these ``` the problem?

Comment: @RafaelPiccinelli i am not familiar with .sql file. i am a beginner,so i use phpmyadmin GUI. So, I posted the error i was given.

Comment: @NawazSohail where do i find mysql error log. I think i have provided the error I got in phpmyadmin

Comment: What are the MySQL versions you used to do the export and to which you're trying to import?

Answer (score 1):

The microsecond fractional part of your DDL (I.e. The (6)) is only supported from MySQL 5.6 onward. Most likely a compatibility issue I'm afraid.

Comment: i ued older version of xampp. i have created few database on it. will they work if i upgrade my xampp

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=xampp+mysql+version+history